# Fast algorithm to pick up metadata from a file based on list of filenames

Tags: php

I have an image gallery with hundreds of image files whose filenames are pulled from a directory using PHP. The filenames are of the form IMG_####.jpg (between 0000 and 9999). There is no guarantee of order or contiguity in the filenames pulled.

I want to be able to attach metadata to some of the images as they are displayed. **I am not implementing a database**. I expect to have the metadata in a text file in some form or other - maybe XML, maybe JSON or something else human-friendly, since it will require a lot of manual data entry.

I want a method that is super light, because I'm loading all these images on a single scrolling page. (All images have been compressed to less than 80K.)

I assume it would take forever to search through an XML or JSON file for a match for **each** of the 600+ images. I think it would be faster if I wrote the metadata directly as an array with 10,000 elements (even though it will be 90% empty). That way, when **IMG_4301.jpg** is pulled, it can immediately attach any metadata from array **element [4301]** without doing any searching at all. How processor-heavy is a 10,000 element array?

That my idea. **Can anyone see a flaw in my solution, or suggest a faster, simpler algorithm?**

For an example of how simple I'm talking, my PHP that parses the directory for the filenames is, like, 10 lines of code:

```
$path = "./images/med/land/";
$prefixLen = strlen($path);    
$files = glob($path . "*.jpg");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    parse_str($str, $output);
    print '         <div class="item">';
    print '             <div class="header">' . substr(substr($image, $prefixLen),0,-4) . '</div>';
    print '             <div class="body"><img src="' . $image . '" alt="" /></div>';
    print '         </div>';
}
```

Comment: So you wish to speed up image lookup or metadata lookup?

Comment: Sorry, did not see this comment. I'm OK with my image processing; I want to ensure I don't kill that advantage by invoking a slow metadata lookup - such as creating an array with 10,000 elements (and then using only 10% of them).